# Could not map index document field to property StartDateTime

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

I have updated my instance from 8.0 initial release to 8.0 update 5. In the Experience profile, there is this error.

> Could not map index document field to property "StartDateTime" on type
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Models.IndexedVisit : String was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime.

I rebuilt the indexes from developer tab in content editor but that did not fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error indicates issues with your analytics index.

First of all (something to do whenever you have errors after an upgrade):
make sure all your files are actually from the correct new version! Verify your bin folder and the Sitecore configs: they have to match with a clean version of the required Sitecore (in this case 8.0 - update5).

If you verified that and the error is still present, check if your upgrade process was completed.

The upgrade guide does mention some steps to take to finalize the upgrade, so make sure you did those:

- Updating Data

> To upgrade your solution from the initial version of Sitecore, 8.0
>   rev. 141212, you must update the social profiles data to ensure that
>   it is compliant with Sitecore 8.0 Update-5. To update the social
>   profiles data, open the following page:
>   http:///sitecore/admin/UpdateSocialProfiles.aspx

- Redeploying Marketing Data

> To update the marketing data to ensure that it is compliant with
>   Sitecore 8.0 Update-5, open the following page:
>   http:///sitecore/admin/RedeployMarketingData.aspx (make sure
>   that analytics is enabled)

- **Rebuilding the Reporting Database**

> As part of the upgrade process, you must also rebuild the Reporting
>   database.

That rebuild of the reporting database is the only way to fix issues with your analytics index (what seems to be the case here). More info on how to do this: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

Comment: I did all those steps. When trying to rebuild index from content tree, the list does not show anything related to "analytics". I have 2 PCs with different instances but same DB. Only one of them has this issue.

Comment: Like I said, you will never find a way to rebuild your analytics index in the admin interfaces. You need to follow the steps of rebuilding the reporting database. Having 2 instances with the same db is another thingy.. that might have been important to mention ;)  An easy fix now should be to copy the index files (in data folder) from the one that is ok to the one that has the issue..

Comment: Copying the indexes fixed the issue. Thank you